# Using Integer Year in Superset time column

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-superset

I have a dataset and I'm using Apache superset for visualization. The only time column that I have in my dataset is "Year" which is in INT type.

```
Year    INT(11)
```

I can't use this value as time in Superset. When I enabled temporal inside superset, I can use that column as time, but all it showed is value "1970". I have year values from 1984 to 2018. But while creating charts it is showing only value 1970.

I tried converting INT year to String and then to Datetime etc. At one point I got all the values converted to 1970 in my MySQL workbench. So I think, while converting this to datetime or any other format, it will get converted to value 1970.

How can I use this column "Year" which is in INT(11) type in the superset. Or is there any way to change or convert this Year to a format that can be read by superset as time or Year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Sources -> Tables`, then choose `Edit record` from the table that you want to modify. Click `Edit record` on the column that you want to convert to date. Now change the `Type` field in the form from `INT` to `DATETIME`. Then type `%Y` in the `Datetime format` field. This should change the data type from integer to year.